# Нужна идея для проекта

Tags: c++

В общем, нужна идея для проекта(всего скорее open source), стаж 4.5 года знаю c++. Проект нужен что-нибудь послабее чем собственная операционная система и сложнее чем сверточная нейронная сеть. Проект по времени где-то на год разработки.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука - [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). Очень часто, для сборки приложений на этом фреймворке, используют такую штуку как [ExpoJS](https://expo.io/). Это облачная система сборки, которая позволяет собрать приложение без проблем конфигурации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, и там прилетают автообновления и проект перестает собираться. Если разработа идет на C++, то я бы предложил используя втроенный в Qt5 JavaScript движок [V4](https://wiki.qt.io/V4), написать JSX Factory, которая позволяла бы применять примитивы QML при построении пользовательского интерфейса в связке React + Redux.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вы убиваете двух зайцев - ущербность состояния приложения при кроссплатформенной разработке на QML и проблему выпуска обособленного приложения при RN + Expo разрботке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже [писал](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/quite) подобное, однако, не довел дело до логического завершения. По ссылке написана вся документалка для рендеринга виртуального древа (в том числе с компонентами), а так же есть **черновая реализация**.